# Mongoose conditional TTL for document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Is there any way to set `expiresAt` index only for some documents, depending on current document state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. You need to set both [partialFilterExpression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) and [expiresAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) indexes. Works only at mongodb 3.2+

Code below will remove document after 24h only if `paid` property is equal to
`false`:

```
let billingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
_id:type:Number,
summ:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
},
description:String,
paid:{
    type:Boolean,
    default:false,
    index:true
},
ownerId:{
    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'User',
    index:true
}
},{timestamps: true,_id: false});
billingSchema.index({createdAt: 1},{expireAfterSeconds: 24*60*60,partialFilterExpression : {paid: false}});
```

Comment: Adding links to the according documentation and explaining how it works would greatly improve your answer.

Comment: The record is expired in 1 minutes if I specify 1 minutes and 5 minutes too.